# ERC721: Do we have to increase token id before or after mint?

Tags: nft, mint

I have this kind of scenario to mint an NFT.

```
_tokenIdTracker.increment();
_safeMint(_to, _tokenId);
```

What I am curious about is which is the right order - Increase token before or after `_safeMint`?

Answer (score 0):

My instinct says that we should update/increment tokenId count after minting. It's obvious if we increment tokenId before minting then very first tokenId => (0) will be useless and it's not mentioned anywhere Or by patrick that tokenId with value 0 isn't accessible. So it should be considered best practice if we increment/update tokenId after minting. But i'm not sure even don't know anything about asynchronous behaviour of blockchain/solidity techno.

```
_safeMint(_to, _tokenId);
_tokenIdTracker.increment();
```

Hope it helps ❤